How to call c++ structure function in c?
$ tree
.
|-- external.c
|-- sc.h
`-- serial_comm.cpp

$ cat external.c 
#include "sc.h"

int main() {
    struct MyStruct* sc;
    sc->myFunction1();
}

$ cat sc.h     
#ifndef SC_H
#define SC_H

struct MyStruct {
    int myVariable;
    void myFunction1();
    void myFunction2();
};

#endif

$ cat serial_comm.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include "sc.h"

extern "C" void MyStruct::myFunction1() {
    std::cout << "Function 1 called" << std::endl;
}

extern "C" void MyStruct::myFunction2() {
    std::cout << "Function 2 called" << std::endl;
}

$ gcc external.c serial_comm.cpp -o my_program -lstdc++ -std=c++17
cc1: warning: command-line option '-std=c++17' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
In file included from external.c:1:
sc.h:6:10: error: field 'myFunction1' declared as a function
    6 |     void myFunction1();
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
sc.h:7:10: error: field 'myFunction2' declared as a function
    7 |     void myFunction2();
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~

I have a project now that requires calling a C++17 structure's function within C language. I expect to receive 'Function 1 called'.
The error message I'm getting is as follows. How should I correct it? Thank you.

member functions are a C++ feature; not available in C.

How should I correct it? -- Don't compile C code as C++.  As you can see, they are two separate languages with differing rules.

The short answer is:  you can't.   C struct types do not have member functions, which are a C++ feature - so there is no way to declare them in C, let alone call them.   The usual approach is for the C code to call an extern "C" function that is defined in C++ that obtains a pointer/reference to the actual object (e.g. from argument(s) passed to it as arguments) and calls the member function.

I advise describing your scenario before posting any code. So does [ask]. (I almost missed the fact that there is text in the question.)

You can put a function pointer in your struct: void (*myFunction1)(void);. But, you have to initialize it with the address of a real function.

Write a C interface library. This kind of thing is done all the time.
mylib.h
The interface itself is written to compile in both C and C++. This is because it is used by both C (for all the C stuff you want to use your library with) and C++ (to compile the wrapper library).
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// Opaque structure type
typedef void mystruct;

mystruct * new_mystruct( int myVarInit );
void delete_mystruct( mystruct * );

int mystruct_getMyVar( mystruct * );
void mystruct_setMyVar( mystruct *, int );

void mystruct_myFunction( mystruct * );

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif

#endif

mylib-c-interface.cpp
This is the wrapper. It gets compiled as C++, but because everything is extern "C" you can link with C code. All it does is wrap calls to your C++ code.
#include "mylib.hpp"  // the C++ header for your library
#include "mylib.h"    // the C header for your library's C wrapper

mystruct * new_mystruct( int myVarInit )
try
{
  mylib::mystruct * S = new mylib::mystruct( myVarInit );
  return (mystruct *) S;
}
catch (...)
{
  // Notice how we don't let exceptions escape the C++ side of things?
  // Memory allocation failure is returned as a NULL pointer.
  return nullptr;
}

void delete_mystruct( mystruct * S )
{
  delete static_cast <mylib::mystruct *> (S);
}

int mystruct_getMyVar( mystruct * S )
{
  return static_cast <mylib::mystruct *> (S)->myVar;
}

void mystruct_setMyVar( mystruct * S, int new_value )
{
  static_cast <mylib::mystruct *> (S)->myVar = new_value;
}

void mystruct_myFunction( mystruct * S )
{
  static_cast <mylib::mystruct *> (S)->myFunction();
}

Linkage
Your C application will have to link with both the mylib and mylib-c-implementation stuff. They don’t necessarily have to be separate things. You could totally combine the C implementation stuff in the same source file as the C++ implementation.
If you are compiling to a DLL (or SO) then it is a good idea to simply provide both sides in the DLL’s symbol table.
But if you only intend to compile to object file before linking to an executable file, you could certainly use a #define to explicitly include the C stuff (so that it doesn’t appear in your executable if it is not needed).
Either way, though, you can no longer compile quick and easy with just one command-line option. You’ll need to individually compile the source files into object files using the correct compiler (C or C++), then link them together to make your executable (or DLL) using the C++ compiler (or the linker directly).
That’s basically it!

The typedef void mystruct; will fail when you try to compile the C++ wrappers.  Use typedef struct mystruct mystruct; instead.

@ChrisDodd It does not fail (and there is no reason it would). Using void makes the using code require usage as a non-obscured pointer. You did get me to fix a couple of stupid errors, though. I suppose some day I will remember not to post untested code on the internet when my sugar is low late at night, lol.

You hzve (had) two definitions for mystruct, which gives an error.  You've since moved the "real" mystruct into namespace mylib, which requires extra static_cast calls.  If you just make it an opaque type (typedef struct mystruct mystruct;) you don't need the static_casts

You misread my original code. The mystruct definitions were always separate — you can look at the revision history if you are unsure. The reason I do not use the opaque type you suggest is because C will not accept a C++ class definition (with member functions and C++ types and all). It cannot just be opaque, it simply cannot be treated as a C struct! Remember, structs in C and C++ are fundamentally different things, and you must be really careful (and explicit with the compiler) in those situations where they are actually the same. It is not the same here.
